# What is time complexity for a set conversion in loop

Tags: python, set, time-complexity

I was wondering what is the time complexity for this piece of code.
The code is basically finding longest substring with K distinct character.
e.g

```
Input: String="araaci", K=2
Output: 4
Explanation: The longest substring with no more than '2' distinct characters is "araa".
```

The loop itself is O(n), but I believe set conversion is also O(n) in python, does that mean my code is basically quadratic O(n<sup>2</sup>) or even slower O(n<sup>3</sup>) because of several set conversion?

```
def longest_substring_with_k_distinct(str1, k):
  result = 0
  window_start = 0
  window_sum = []
  list_str = list(str1)

  for window_end in range(len(list_str)):
    window_sum.append(list_str[window_end])
    
    if len(set(window_sum)) <= k:
      result = max(result, len(window_sum))

    while len(set(window_sum)) > k:
      window_sum.pop(0)
      window_start += 1

  return result
```

Comment: Looks like O(n³). `set(window_sum)` looks like O(n). `while len(set(window_sum)) > k` looks like O(n²). That inside a for-loop looks like O(n³). I don't know exactly what your algorithm is doing, so there might be some subtlety in there that I'm missing, but O(n³) is a likely guess.

Comment: There is something fishy here - for one `window_start` is not used

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://blog.finxter.com/python-set-to-list/#Python_Set_to_List_Complexity) and also to [a text from UCI](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Epattis/ICS-33/lectures/complexitypython.txt), it seems that the conversion of *list* to a *set* is of O(n).
So,  your code runs in O(n<sup>2</sup>) in all cases.

About the O(n<sup>3</sup>), no, it does not increase your complexity to O(n<sup>3</sup>). Follow along...
*You're running the for loop **n** times and in each iteration, you are running the set conversion twice. So **n** times **2n** will be **2n<sup>2</sup>** wich is still evaluated as O(n<sup>2</sup>).*
Still, if it doesn't satisfy you, convert the list to a set and evaluate the length at the beginning of the for loop. Then it'll make much more scene to you.
On the other hand, if I were you, I would have evaluated the length of each element beforehand and just simply use it in the for-loop. That way you're guaranteed with an O(n) complexity :)

Comment: Nothing on that wiki page says list-to-set conversion usually takes O(1) time. Inserting *one* element into a set usually takes O(1) time. Inserting a *whole list's worth* of elements cannot be done in O(1). That wouldn't even be enough time to read the input.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You were right, I edited the post.